# How communicate between multiple raspberry pi's over the internet?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am working on a project with raspberry pi. I have a little experience with raspberry pi, but not so much.

The project is as folows:
There are 3 raspberry pi's with each a camera. One raspberry pi is the master, and the other two are the slaves. Each raspberry takes a photo and send it to the master. So that the master can put the photos in an document. I was thinking of creating a python script.
The pi's communicate with each other over the internet. (IP addresses are fixed)

I'm not sure what to use for this. What's the best way I can do this?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming issue. Maybe ask at [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se].

Comment: So the master RasPi is going to create a document, of an unspecified type, containing 2 photos and that's it?